# How to get webp image EXIF metadata in lua?

Tags: lua, exif, webp, openresty, luajit

I can get this data with the following code. But it runs too slow:

```lua
local handle = io.popen("exiftool image.webp")
local result = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()
```

Is there a more elegant way to get the metadata?

UPD:

I use this software:

- docker (20.10.7)
- openresty/openresty:xenial (1.15.8.3)
- luarocks (3.2.1)
- LuaJIT (2.1.0-beta3)

Here is an example of a picture with a UserComment field: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ie7lTBvc1BhbsUiiBRdDXwnOVdIGmcf8/view?usp=sharing)

Exiftool sees this property:

```sh
$ exiftool -EXIF:UserComment Johnrogershousemay2020.webp  
User Comment                    : {"foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: In other words, you want to get webp image width and height?

Comment: No, I need to get information from the UserComment field

Comment: asking for software recommendations is against the guidelines. so either ask about a problem using a specific library/software or ask about issues while implementing one yourself (add more code then).

Comment: Can you provide an example of webp file having UserComment field?

Comment: I added an example picture, as well as information about the software

Comment: Can't download image.  GoogleDrive link is private, it says "You need access".

Comment: Sorry, I have not checked the access settings. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is less elegant, but it does not require to run external application :-)

```
function get_webp_user_comment(file_name)
   local file = io.open(file_name, "rb")
   local exif_offset, exif_found, is_big_endian, user_comment = 12

   local function read_string(offset, size)
      file:seek("set", offset)
      return file:read(size)
   end

   local function read_uint(offset, size)
      local n, s = 0, read_string(offset, size)
      for j = 1, size do
         n = n * 256 + s:byte(is_big_endian and j or size + 1 - j)
      end
      return n
   end

   local function read_uint32(disp)
      return read_uint(exif_offset + disp, 4)
   end

   local function read_uint16(disp)
      return read_uint(exif_offset + disp, 2)
   end

   local function search_for_tag(ifd_disp, tag)
      if ifd_disp ~= 0 then
         local entry_disp = ifd_disp + 2
         for j = 1, read_uint16(ifd_disp) do
            if read_uint16(entry_disp) == tag then
               return read_uint32(entry_disp + 8), read_uint32(entry_disp + 4)
            end
            entry_disp = entry_disp + 12
         end
         return search_for_tag(read_uint32(entry_disp), tag)
      end
   end

   if read_string(0, 4) == "RIFF" and read_string(8, 4) == "WEBP" then
      local max_offset = read_uint32(-8)
      while exif_offset < max_offset do
         local section_name = read_string(exif_offset, 4)
         exif_offset = exif_offset + 8
         if section_name == "EXIF" then
            local endianness = read_string(exif_offset, 2)
            is_big_endian = endianness == "MM"
            exif_found = is_big_endian or endianness == "II"
            if exif_found then
               break
            end
         end
         exif_offset = exif_offset + read_uint32(-4)
         exif_offset = exif_offset + exif_offset % 2
      end
   end
   if exif_found then
      local exif_ifd = search_for_tag(read_uint32(4), 0x8769)
      if exif_ifd then
         local disp, count = search_for_tag(exif_ifd, 0x9286)
         user_comment = read_string(exif_offset + disp + 8, count - 8)
      end
   end
   file:close()
   return user_comment
end
```

Usage example:

```
local file_name = "path/to/Johnrogershousemay2020.webp"
print(get_webp_user_comment(file_name))
```

Comment: Maybe "less elegant" but much more independant since it doesn't rely on (executing) 3rd party software. The code would be much more valuable with comments and using constants for magic numbers (`0x8769` is IFD_Exif, `0x9286` is EXIF's user comment, but Windows XP's comment `0x9c9c` is nowhere mentioned).

Comment: @AmigoJack - Can you provide an image having `0x9c9c` comment?

Comment: [github.com/drewnoakes/.../windowsXpFields.jpg](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/blob/master/Tests/Data/windowsXpFields.jpg) and similarly named files in that repo.

Comment: @AmigoJack - Are you talking about `XP Comment` field?  It's another field.  OP wants only `User Comment` field (probably there is some protocol for saving JSON data in it?)

Comment: What else did you think was meant with my comment? I even provided the TIFF ID. And no, neither `0x9286` nor `0x9c9c` are meant for JSON - no reader would expect that. Windows XP's comment field is always saved in UCS2 encoding. Yes, OP only meant "UserComment", but when reading files I'd be rather prepared for all types of comments.

Comment: @AmigoJack - My guess about a custom protocol for storing JSON in `UserComment` was inspired by the example in the question, not by your comment.  AFAIU OP does not have a task to read all fields that may contain comments, so there is no reason to search for `0x9c9c` tag.

Comment: Thank you, this is a pretty interesting way, I'll try to apply it. I really only need to read one field "UserComment"

Comment: I also managed to get the desired result using the [magick](https://luarocks.org/modules/leafo/magick) package, but this requires Imagemagick to be configured with the webp support flag

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is 'UserComment', then pass that as a parameter during your popen call:

```
local handle = io.popen("exiftool -EXIF:UserComment image.webp")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, opening new popen processes is too resource intensive.